# What do I use as my password? (not really)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, video-games

Just experimenting with something nerdy.  Not certain that this will work.

```
special = 0  
soviets = 2  
without = 1  
fantasy = 0  
bullets = 3  
tyrants = 4  
nuclear = 1  
muddled = 2
zappers = 1  
violent = 0
Murders = 3
hacking = 0  
grenade = 0
moments = 4
gunners = 2
errands = 3 
fifties = 1
madness = 2
killing = 0
botanic = 3
muscles = 3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

> "Mutants". The video game tag gave it away, It's similar to puzzles in fallout 3.

This is how I worked it out.

> In Fallout there is a hacking puzzle game. Each incorrect word gives you a number, that number is equal to the number of characters in the same location as the correct password. I used the words with a score of 0 to determine which letters could not be in the correct word. Then from the remaining characters I calculated based upon the value of the words they were in how likely it was for them to appear in the final answer. 
>  [image]

Comment: Can you explain how you solved this? I don't understand that table.

Comment: In Fallout there is a hacking puzzle game. Each incorrect word gives you a number, that number is equal to the number of characters in the same location as the correct password. I used the words with a score of 0 to determine which letters could not be in the correct word. Then from the remaining characters I calculated based upon the value of the words they were in how likely it was for them to appear in the final answer.

Comment: This may give more insight into the hacking minigame in Fallout http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Basic_concept_of_computer_hacking%3F